# Why shva nach when it should be a chataf patach?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, vowels-nekudot, parashat-ki-tisa

[Shmot 31:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0231.htm#4) says

> לַחְשֹׁב, מַחֲשָׁבֹת; לַעֲשׂוֹת בַּזָּהָב וּבַכֶּסֶף, וּבַנְּחֹשֶׁת

Why does the word לחשוב have a shvah under the chet when normally a Peh-Gronit shoresh in the Pa'al binyan has a chataf-patach under the first shoresh letter in the שם הפועל?

I know that I have seen the same word spelled with a chataf-patach in Chumash before. Also, the following word has a chataf-patach where I would expect it to be.

Comment: What's the difference between a Shva na and a chataf patach?

Comment: @DoubleAA What do you mean? A chet cannot take a shva-na as far as I know. The shva under this chet is a shva nach, but a Peh-gronit is supposed to take a chataf patach in this situation.

Comment: @DoubleAA Let me partially retract that statement.  I am pretty sure that a chet cannot take a shva-na *as the first letter of the shoresh* (at least in a Pa'al verb)

Comment: So too the other place the word לחשב appears in Tanach, http://kodesh.snunit.k12.il/i/t/t2816.htm#30
עֹצֶה עֵינָיו, לַחְשֹׁב תַּהְפֻּכוֹת;    קֹרֵץ שְׂפָתָיו, כִּלָּה רָעָה

Answer (score 5):

You are correct in that a I-guttural (a *peh-gronit* verb) usually takes a composite *shewa* (although be mindful of the fact that it's not always with *patach*), but the major exception to this is where it appears in a closed syllable, after the *lamed* of the infinite construct, in which it often (although not always) takes a regular *shewa*.

So, for example, חֲסוֹת but לַחְסוֹת (Isaiah 30:14), עֲזוֹר but לַעְזוֹר (II Samuel 18:3), חֲצוֹב but לַחְצוֹב (Jeremiah 2:13), etc. And, of course, the example you gave, which can also be seen in Exodus 35:32, Proverbs 16:30 and II Chronicles 2:13.

If you would like to see a discussion of this in grammatical literature, see Gesenius §63i or Joüon and Muraoka §68e.

Comment: And don't forget ["לאסור אסר"](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%9C_%D7%92)!